# add a default value to an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, opencart

I have the following code in my opencart product.php control file.

```
$product_option_value_data = array();

        foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
            $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                'option_value_id'         => $product_option_value['option_value_id'],
                'quantity'                => isset ($product_option_value['quantity']) ? $product_option_value['quantity'] : '1',
                'subtract'                => $product_option_value['subtract'],
                'price'                   => isset ($product_option_value['price'])? $product_option_value['price'] : '27.99',
                'price_prefix'            => $product_option_value['price_prefix'],
                'points'                  => $product_option_value['points'],
                'points_prefix'           => $product_option_value['points_prefix'],                        
                'weight'                  => $product_option_value['weight'],
                'weight_prefix'           => $product_option_value['weight_prefix'] 
            );
        }
```

I need to add default value to quantity, price, subtract.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: looks almost working , what are the errors you are getting

Comment: I think you have added default value to quantity and price.

Comment: `'subtract'                =>  isset($product_option_value['subtract']) ? isset($product_option_value['subtract']) : '0',`

Comment: I thought I did it, but when I am using the code in opencart, it does not add the default value. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You have done that for two of your elements. Just add the same check for the `subtract` one.

```
$product_option_value_data = array();
    foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
        $product_option_value_data[] = array(
            'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
            'option_value_id'         => $product_option_value['option_value_id'],
            'quantity'                => 
                   isset ($product_option_value['quantity']) ?
                          $product_option_value['quantity'] :
                          '1', // THE DEFAULT FOR QUANTITY
            'subtract'                =>  
                    isset ($product_option_value['subtract']) ? 
                           $product_option_value['subtract'] :
                           '22', // THE DEFAULT FOR SUBTRACK
            'price'                   => 
                    isset ($product_option_value['price']) ? 
                           $product_option_value['price'] : 
                           '27.99', //THE DEFAULT FOR PRICE
            'price_prefix'            => $product_option_value['price_prefix'],
            'points'                  => $product_option_value['points'],
            'points_prefix'           => $product_option_value['points_prefix'],                        
            'weight'                  => $product_option_value['weight'],
            'weight_prefix'           => $product_option_value['weight_prefix'] 
        );
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought I did it, but when I am using the code in opencart, it does not add the default value. Am I missing anything here?